# Copy an Entire String from a Keyword

Tags: c#, string, find

So, I want to do this, 
For example, there is a string called [FULLNAME]-Awesome Guy-[END],
But there are multiple strings in a list, so like:
    [OTHER]-AG-[END]
    [FULLNAME]-Awesome Guy-[END]
    [NICKNAME]-AG-[END]

My question is, how can I find [FULLNAME] then set a string as [FULLNAME]-Awesome Guy-[END]
Can you guys help?

Thanks!

Comment: string fullName = recList.Contains("[FULLNAME]").ToString();
But that doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: IndexOf? Substring? Regex? Have you tried anything, or do you simply wish us to do your work for you?

Comment: What I have said above is ALL I have tried, because nothing else seems rational..

Comment: Really? Nothing seems rational, but recList.Contains("...").ToString() does?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good explanation of a problem for SO. Please put some effort into showing your attampts to solve it AND explain what you expected and what you don't understand in result of code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd probably recommend using a regular expression here if you just need something quick. if you need something more robust and able to handle breaking up the various tags, you might want to look at writing up your own basic parser to break stuff up by tag and let you search that way.

this code:

```
 string s = "[OTHER]-AG-[END] [FULLNAME]-Awesome Guy-[END] [NICKNAME]-AG-[END]";
 Regex re = new Regex(@"\[FULLNAME\][^[]+\[END\]");
 Console.WriteLine(re.Match(s));
```

prints

```
[FULLNAME]-Awesome Guy-[END]
```

although it will give you malformed results if there is a `[` character in the name somewhere.